# Emails are rejected when using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have problem with `MailApp.sendEmail()`.
I try to send email by script in Google Spreadsheet. My script works on my account, but does not work on my friend's account. I get this message:

> Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; xx@xx.xx
> Action: failed
> Status: 5.0.0
> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.
> Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 05:41:31 -0700 (PDT)

I used the Martin Hawksey tutorial script (with some modifications):

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "xxx@gmail.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
function formatHtmlMailBody(obj, order) {
    var result = "html text";
    // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
    for (var idx in order) {
        var key = order[idx];
        result += key + " " + obj[key];
    }
    return result;
}

function formatTextMailBody(obj, order) {
    var result = "text";
    for (var idx in order) {
        var key = order[idx];
        result += key + "\n" + obj[key] + "\n\n";
    }
    return result;
}

function doPost(e) {

    try {
        Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
        record_data(e);

        var mailData = e.parameters;

        var dataOrder = JSON.parse(e.parameters.formDataNameOrder);

        var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;
        MailApp.sendEmail(
            String(sendEmailTo),
            'title',
            formatTextMailBody(mailData, dataOrder), {             // body
                htmlBody: formatHtmlMailBody(mailData, dataOrder), // advanced options
                name: "name",
                replyTo: String(mailData.Email)
            }
        );
        //second mail
        try {
            var htmlBodyToSender = "html text";
            var textBodyToSender = "text";
            MailApp.sendEmail(
                String(mailData.Email), //to
                'title', //subject
                textBodyToSender, {                        // body
                    htmlBody: htmlBodyToSender,            // advanced options
                    name: "name",
                    replyTo: String(sendEmailTo)
                }
            );
        }
        catch (error) {
            Logger.log(error);
        }

        return ContentService    // return json success results
            .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({
                "result": "success",
                "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters)
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } catch (error) { // if error return this
        Logger.log(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: having the same problem, hope someone knows how to fix.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I am using a G Suite account, but Google support is no help.

Answer (score 1):

**Delivery Status Notification**

The message content is governed by ["An Extensible Message Format for Delivery Status Notifications"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464#section-2.3) since it is a delivery status notification (DSN) for the failed email. Let's parse the error message field by field:

1. **Final-Recipient: [rfc822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822); xx@xx.xx** - just a pointer to the type and address of the recipient *after* all modifications of forwarding or gatewaying.
2. **Action: failed** - an enum representing delivery status, can be `failed`, `delayed`, `delivered`, `relayed`, or `expanded`. In your case it indicates that the email failed to be delivered.
3. **Status: 5.0.0** - email delivery status codes are governed by [RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463#section-3.6), and the `500` error just means "Other or undefined protocol status" without further clarification.
4. **Diagnostic-Code: smtp;** - contains the type and reason of failure (is present only for "action" field with `failed` or `delayed` value). Nothing too specific in your case, Google simply points to the list of possible bounce reasons.
5. **Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 05:41:31 -0700 (PDT)** - finally, this field contains a timestamp of the last time of attempting to, quoting the standard, "relay, gateway, or deliver" the email.

**The problem**

As you can see from the above, the error does not mean there is anything wrong with your code. This also explains why the script "works" for some accounts: the problem is either with Google's infrastructure or with the intended recipient's security configuration.

Since the first is usually accompanied by a more specific DSN, you should check the email security configuration of the account(s) affected. In case everything looks normal, switch to `GmailApp`'s similar [`sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) method that gives you a more fine-grained control or use the [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#request-body) which allows you to construct the message from scratch.

Comment: Switching from MailApp to GmailApp fixed the issue for me